# learning rate in DL/ML with parser argument

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch

what is meant by 1e-2,1e-3,or 4e-3 while defining learning rate in pytorch with Parser argument
which number is used is for decimal and which one is for value
does 1e-3 means =0.0001 or it means 0.3?

Here defined in Code
"parser.add_argument('--lr', type=float, nargs='+', default=[4e-2], help='learning rate')"

Answer (score 1):

This is the e-notation which signifies which power of `10` to multiply the amount with.

```
1e-2 = 1*10**-2 = 0.01
1e-3 = 1*10**-3 = 0.001
4e-3 = 4*10**-3 = 0.004
```

So in pseudo-code `xen` is equal to `x*10**n`

Comment: Please consider accepting this answer as valid. Thank you.